# How do I perform row arithmetic in OpenCVSharp?

Tags: c#, opencv

In c++ I can perform row arithmetic on a matrix:

```
Mat pPrime = Mat::ones(Size(3, 3), CV_64F); 
pPrime.row(0) = pPrime.row(0) / pPrime.row(2);
```

Is it possible to perform row arithmetic with OpenCVSharp? Trying to duplicate the c++ code results in the error `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer`

```
Mat pPrime = Mat.Ones(new Size(3, 3), MatType.CV_64F).ToMat();
pPrime.Row(0) = pPrime.Row(0) / pPrime.Row(1);
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but I was looking for the answer to this and found the answer in the opencvsharp repo [here](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/883#issuecomment-597961271)

Your example would translate to this:

```
Mat pPrime = Mat.Ones(new Size(3, 3), MatType.CV_64F).ToMat();
using var pPrimeRow0 = pPrime.Row(0);
using var pPrimeRowDevided = pPrime.Row(0) / pPrime.Row(1);
pPrimeRowDevided.CopyTo(pPrimeRow0);
```